# OnQueueError not firing on task queue: NestJS + Bull

Tags: nestjs, bull

I've noticed that bull does not print exceptions to the console by default. To get around this I want to catch errors with the `@OnQuerueError` decorator and print them to the console (for now). My current implementation does not work and I don't understand why. The `handler` is not called. I verified that other event listeners work such as `@OnQueueActive()`:

```
@Processor('email')
export default class DigestEmailProcessor {
    constructor(
    ) {}

    @OnQueueError()
    handler() {
        console.log('fired exception');
    }

    @Process(PROCESS_NAMES.email.send)
    async send(job: Job<JobData>) {
        throw new Error("Foo bar")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener `@OnQueueError()` is not correct for this use case.
Try using the event listener `@OnQueueFailed()` this raises an event for jobs that have thrown an error.

using your example code:

```js
@Processor('email')
export default class DigestEmailProcessor {
    constructor(
    ) {}

    @OnQueueFailed()
    handler(job: Job, error: Error) {
        console.log('fired exception');
    }

    @Process(PROCESS_NAMES.email.send)
    async send(job: Job<JobData>) {
        throw new Error("Foo bar")
    }
}
```

more information on the different [event listeners](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues#event-listeners)

Comment: Would that also handle when the connection is lost? We are having issues handling errors like too many connections or when Redis goes offline